# Фризы при повороте камеры в играх

Tags: windows

Компьютеру пару месяцев. Все железо новое. Все подключено правильно (двуканал, PCIe 4.0, ссд в правильном слоте). Все это время мучаюсь от лагов при прогрузке новых текстур, проблема особенно заметна становится когда первый раз вхожу в игру и поворачиваю камеру вправо-влево, открываю инвентарь и тд (текстуры еще не закешировались и прогружаются первый раз). Когда второй раз делаю то же самое действие - лагов уже нет.

Актуально в таких играх как: Atomic Heart, Sons of the Forest, Dirt Rally. Самое интересное в том, что если даже выкрутить настройки графики на минимум - лаги все равно будут.

Никак не могу понять с чем связан проблема... MSI Afterbunner не показывает аномалий по нагрузке. Пытаюсь разобраться уже несколько месяцев, но никак не выходит. Добрые люди, помогите.

Мой бенч: https://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/66066913
Nvidia 3D выставлен на "баланс"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не думаю, что тут тебе помогут. Профиль сайта немного про другое. Тебе наверное на какой-нить Оверлокерс или типа того.